# Pin code not working on ENTER button

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

When I enter `pin code` and click on enter button it is not working though its  working on mouse click. How to solve it?

```
<div class="input-box">
    <div class="z-btn">
        <label>Zip Code : </label><input type="text" id="cod" class="product-custom-option" name="cod" value="" placeholder="Enter pincode">
        <button type="button" onclick="checkCOD();" name="zip-check" title="Check" class="button" id="zip-check"><span>Check</span></button>
    </div>
    <div id="cod_msg"></div>
</div>
```

My Script as follows :

```
<script>
    function checkCOD(){
        var cod = $('cod').value;
        if(cod == ''){
            $('cod_msg').update('<span class="cod-error"><?php echo $msgData['emp_msg']; ?></span>');
            return
        }else{
            $('cod_msg').update('<img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl( Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB, true ).'media/cod/img/ajax-loader-2.gif';?>">'); 
            new Ajax.Request('<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl().'netgo/cod/check';?>', {
                method:'post',
                parameters: {zipcode: cod}, 
                onSuccess: function(transport) {
                    var response = transport.responseText || "no response text";
                    $('cod_msg').update(response);
                },
                onFailure: function() { alert('Something went wrong...'); }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: please share the code or the extension name you used. Without code we cant help you

Comment: you can share it here. Just edit the questiion with the code

Comment: @RiddhishBhayani, check my edit in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by adding a small Js function `keypress event`, Since you haven't posted your code, I show you an example:

Replace :

```
<script>
    function checkCOD(){
        var cod = $('cod').value;
        if(cod == ''){
            $('cod_msg').update('<span class="cod-error"><?php echo $msgData['emp_msg']; ?></span>');
            return
        }else{
            $('cod_msg').update('<img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl( Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB, true ).'media/cod/img/ajax-loader-2.gif';?>">'); 
            new Ajax.Request('<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl().'netgo/cod/check';?>', {
                method:'post',
                parameters: {zipcode: cod}, 
                onSuccess: function(transport) {
                    var response = transport.responseText || "no response text";
                    $('cod_msg').update(response);
                },
                onFailure: function() { alert('Something went wrong...'); }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

with :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkCOD(){
            var cod = $('cod').value;
            if(cod == ''){
                $('cod_msg').update('<span class="cod-error"><?php echo $msgData['emp_msg']; ?></span>');
                return
            }else{
                $('cod_msg').update('<img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl( Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB, true ).'media/cod/img/ajax-loader-2.gif';?>">'); 
                new Ajax.Request('<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl().'netgo/cod/check';?>', {
                    method:'post',
                    parameters: {zipcode: cod}, 
                    onSuccess: function(transport) {
                        var response = transport.responseText || "no response text";
                        $('cod_msg').update(response);
                    },
                    onFailure: function() { alert('Something went wrong...'); }
                });
            }
    }
    //the add
    jQuery('document').ready(function(){
        jQuery('#cod').keypress(function(e){
                if(e.which == 13){//The Enter key pressed
                    jQuery('#zip-check').click();
                }
         });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It's a very simple code, go to your page where you have this pin code product view i imagine ? so you find it in: `app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml` then check the id of the input text (the pin code) than replace `#pin_code` in js code with the other id

Comment: look now please

Comment: Not working plz check once again

Comment: Its should work, i tested it and it works ! look again your code, dont forget to clear you browser and Magento cache !

Comment: I remove all caches Not working plz check once again

Comment: Check my update .

Comment: I remove all caches and tried Not working plz check once again

Comment: I tried but not working please answer me

Comment: I haven't idea, the answer that I gave you work fine for me

Comment: https://www.depoto.com/large-angle-grinder-dewalt-d28491-html.html           please check our website

Comment: you have an error in your js code : `$('document').ready(function(){
        $('#cod').keypress(function(e){
                if(e.which == 13){//The Enter key pressed
                    $('#zip-check').click();
                }
            });
        } //remove this<-
    });`

Comment: remove your code and past again my answer, You have badly coppied my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61997/discussion-between-nukala-satish-and-prince).

Comment: it works ???...

Comment: I see that you have an conflict in your JS website, in my code replace `$` with `jQuery` and it will work

Comment: sorry for delay.It is not working. Sorry how i am replace it.Please tell me prince

Comment: sorry for delay. I replace $ with jQuery but not working.Please tell me prince

Comment: copy and past my code again

Comment: sorry for delay Thank you for your responses Prince it is working now

Comment: Oooof, finally :)

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: Prince I have one doubt please give me answer I share the link where i will place this code

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vxbU1lcP5Hpt9SLFBa4GxXh-tPnaaufHZh-NbLUyXg0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: https://puppetkart.com/etikoppaka/car.html

Comment: I have confused where i am placing the jQuery code

Comment: I didn't understand your question, it worked before !

Comment: yes it worked.I want to apply in another website prince.my problem is i confused where i placed the iQuery code  in my view.phtml file

Comment: please see the code  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vxbU1lcP5Hpt9SLFBa4GxXh-tPnaaufHZh-NbLUyXg0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: look your doc now

Comment: I replaced but not working     https://puppetkart.com/etikoppaka/car.html